# Using @FetchRequest within a func produces "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View"

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I have a detail view that displays a compartment name and a list of the inventory in that compartment. The object in the var `compartment` is passed in from the preceding list view.

Because I am using a @FetchRequest with the passed is compartment as predicate to populate the list of inventory, I cannot make the FetchRequest before the instance of 'compartment' is initialized. Therefore, I placed it in a func and call it from within the view, after the compartment object has been passed through. This does not cause any build errors, however it does produce the following runtime error:

`Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.`

Below is the full code of the detail view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CompartmentDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    var compartment = Compartment()   
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            let inventories = getInventory()
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(inventories) { i in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: InventoryDetailView(inventory:i),
                            label: {
                                HStack(spacing: 20.0) {
                                    Text(i.name)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 30)
        .navigationTitle(compartment.name)
    }
    
    func getInventory() -> [Inventory] {
        @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "compartment == \"\(compartment.name)\""))
        var inventories: FetchedResults<Inventory>
        return Array(inventories)
    }
    
}
```

I have tried putting the contents of the func within an .onAppear statement attached to the ScrollView, but that doesn't make `inventories` available to the view

Comment: `FetchRequest` should be at `struct` level not inside a `func`

Comment: Declare the fetch request at the struct level as mentioned but without a predicate and then create and set the predicate in a custom init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
...
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(value: false),
        animation: .default)
    private var inventories: FetchedResults<Inventory>

    let compartment: Compartment
 
    var body: some View {
...

            let _ = updatePredicate()
            ForEach(inventories) { i in
...
    
    func updatePredicate() {
        inventories.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "compartment == %@", compartment)
    }
    
}
```

Unfortunately the `NSPredicate` object is recreated more often than necessary but there is not much we can do about the Core Data team's bad design choice of using property wrapper for the fetch. (They should have used a view modifier similar to `onChange` and `task`).

Comment: Thanks malhal. I wasn't aware that I could change the predicate after completing the fetch request. This makes total sense in that context: do the `@FetchRequest` up front in the struct, and revise the predicate later after `compartment` has been resolved.